# Hadoop streaming with private python interpreter

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to use Hadoop streaming with a private python interpreter (Hortonworks data platform 2.2.0). The python interpreter is private in the sense that it is a virtual environment interpreter in a home directory and only the specific user account has permission to run it.

I am specifying the python interpreter in the hashbang line. My streaming job works with the system python or with `#!/usr/bin/env python`. However, it produces a permission denied error when I use the private python interpreter:
`#!/home/dmazur/test/tempenv/bin/python`

Here is a segment of the output that shows the error message:

```
15/11/03 11:31:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/11/03 11:31:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1440596114865_0249_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/gs/hadoop/yarn/local/lm-2r01-n10/usercache/dmazur/appcache/application_1440596114865_0249/container_1440596114865_0249_01_000002/./mapper_mean.py": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more
```

I believe the problem is with permissions on the python interpreter and not with the mapper_mean.py file. When the hashbang line is changed without changing the permissions on the file itself, the job runs fine. I imagine this means that the MapReduce job is run by a daemon process owned by another user. I haven't seen anything in the documentation about how to use a private interpreter for Hadoop streaming. Is it possible? If so, what permissions need to be set to let it run?

Answer (score 0):

For running such a job u need a user who the permission to run the executable /home/dmazur/test/tempenv/bin/python and also the have permission to initiate the hadoop job as well.
then it should go fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The user in this case has permissions to run the executable and is also initiating the Hadoop job. There are apparently some additional permissions required, because of the error described in the question. Ideally, I am hoping for a list of permissions required for using the interpreter with Hadoop streaming.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be worked around by moving the virtual environment to a new directory and setting permissions so that it can be executed by all users.

I have tested this and it has allowed me to use the virtual environment. However, it is not a satisfying solution because there may be privacy/security concerns with making the interpreter readable/executable to all users. So, it would still be very valuable to have a list of the minimum required permissions for a Hadoop streaming interpreter as well as an explanation of why the problem arises.